# Help with function limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to say whether the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y),$$
exists, where
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{|x^{3}|+|y^{3}|}.$$
Can anyone give a hand?

Comment: let $y=kx$ and $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)$ changed to $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$

Comment: This limit really exist? Take $y=x^{1/3}$ then we get $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^{2+ \frac{2}{3}} }{|x|^3+|x|}$$ and this limit does not exist.

Comment: The limit does exist. Notice that if $x<0$ then $|x|^3+|x| \equiv -x^3-x \equiv -x(x^2+1)$. If $x>0$ then $|x|^3 + |x| \equiv x^3 + x \equiv x(x^2+1)$. In both cases we can cancel a factor of $x$ from the numerator and denominator and we get:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{\pm}} \frac{x^{2+\frac{2}{3}}}{|x|^3+|x|} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \pm\frac{x^{5/3}}{x^2+1} = 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

I like to use polar coordinates for questions like this. Let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{|x^3|+|y^3|} \equiv \frac{r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}{|r^3\cos^3\theta|+|r^3\sin^3\theta|} \equiv r \left(\frac{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}{|\cos^3\theta|+|\sin^3\theta|}\right)$$

As $r$ tends to zero, this limit tends towards zero, *independently* of the choice of $\theta$.

I've plotted an image of the function $z = x^2y^2/(|x^3|+|y^3|)$ for $x$ and $y$ within the circle, centre $(0,0)$ with radius $1/5$ and this seems to confirm a well-defined limit. The limit is $z=0$, but I haven't included axes.

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of putting some modulus signs in your last denominator (the $\cos^3$ and $\sin^3$ terms) since I assume you left them out by accident (if you don't have them I worry about division by zero). I won't be offended if you revert or whatever.

Comment: @BenMillwood Well spotted! Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the function is not continuous at the point in question and so we can’t just plug in the point.  So, since the function is not continuous at the point there is at least a chance that the limit doesn’t exist.  If we could find two different paths to approach the point that gave different values for the limit then we would know that the limit didn’t exist. Two of the more common paths to check are the x and y-axis so let’s try those.

x-axis (y = 0)
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{|x^{3}|+|y^{3}|} = 
\lim_{(x,0)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}(0)^{2}}{|x^{3}|+|(0)^{3}|} = \lim_{(x,0)\to(0,0)}0 = 0$$
So along the x-axis the function will approach zero as we move in towards the origin.

y-axis (x = 0)
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{|x^{3}|+|y^{3}|} = 
\lim_{(0,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(0)^{2}y^{2}}{|(0)^{3}|+|y^{3}|} = \lim_{(0,y)\to(0,0)}0 = 0$$

Although both limits converge at 0 this does not mean that there exists a limit, this only means that the limits exists along two paths.

Let's take a look at the path y = x to confirm:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{|x^{3}|+|y^{3}|} = 
\lim_{(x,x)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}x^{2}}{|x^{3}|+|x^{3}|} = 
\lim_{(x,x)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^4}{2x^3} = 
\lim_{(x,x)\to(0,0)}\frac{x}{2} = 0$$

This gives us the same value as the previous two paths, therefore it is safe to conclude that a limit of 0 exists.